# Django - How do I Iterate through a list of dictionaries to concatenate values from a same element

Tags: python, django

I have a list of dictionaries as follows:

```
listDict = [{'product':'sandwich','price':'5200'}, {'product':'hamburger','price':'3000'}]
```

to iterate through the elements i do:

```
{%for element in listDict%}
    {% for key,value in element.items %}
        <input type="checkbox" name = "bar" value = "{{ value }}">{{ value }}<br>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

this, as expected, will print:

```
sandwich

5200

hamburger

3000
```

but how could I concatenate the values in order to print something like this:

```
sandwich - 5200

hamburger - 3000
```

I can't do something like below:

```
for element in listDict:
    element['product']+" - "+element['price']
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can just do this:

```
{%for element in listDict%}
    {{ element.product }} - {{ element.price }}
{% endfor %}
```